# Dockerfile for Mariadb image

Tags: mariadb, dockerfile

While creating the docker image, I would like to add a database and import schema. When I tried, I got the below error.

> 160829 22:32:44 mysqld_safe Logging to
>   '/var/lib/mysql/2da0903ff372.err'. 160829 22:32:44 mysqld_safe
>   Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/ mysql 160829
>   22:32:47 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
>   ende d ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through
>   socket '/var/run /mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")
>   The command '/bin/sh -c /bin/bash -c "/usr/bin/mysqld_safe &" && sleep
>   5 && mysq l -u root -e "CREATE DATABASE portal" && mysql -u root
>   portal < /tmp/ddl.sql && mysql -u root portal < /tmp/dml.sql' returned
>   a non-zero code: 1

Below is the Dockerfile what I am using to create the image.

```
FROM mariadb:latest
# Author
MAINTAINER Anvar 
# Add files 
ADD my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf
ADD ddl.sql /tmp/ddl.sql
ADD dml.sql /tmp/dml.sql

RUN  /bin/bash -c "/usr/bin/mysqld_safe &" && sleep 5 && mysql -u root -CREATE DATABASE portal" && mysql -u root portal < /tmp/ddl.sql`
```

Please advice where am I doing wrong?.

Comment: When you have a small look the in the entrypoint script https://github.com/docker-library/mariadb/blob/d969a465ee48fe10f4b532276f7337ddaaf3fc36/10.1/docker-entrypoint.sh of the mariaDB image. You can see that at first start the db is initialized. Your tasks are run far early with not existing runable db server in the container.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response Rene M. Actually, my requirement is to create a docker image with pre populated database schema along with data. Is there a way to achieve it?

Comment: Extend the entrypoint to your needs

Comment: Thanks again. I was looking at docker-entrypoint.sh and figured out a solution. Simply, I need to copy my sql files both DDL and DML one after another inside /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/* . Below is the corrected code.                                                                                         `FROM mariadb:latest
# Author
MAINTAINER Anvar 
# Add files 
ADD my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf
ADD ddl.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ddl.sql
ADD dml.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/dml.sql`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply, I need to copy my sql files both DDL and DML one after another inside /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/* . Below is the corrected code. docker-entrypoint.sh has the logic to execute them when we spin the container.

```
FROM mariadb:latest
# Author
MAINTAINER Anvar 
# Add files 
ADD my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf
ADD ddl.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ddl.sql
ADD dml.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/dml.sql
```